# Can you help me identify this LEGO, knex type set? bag with black, grey, red, yellow and light brown

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

I got this in a pile of stuff I won at an auction. It says LEGO 2017 and says it’s bag 1, 649R1 and the QR code gives the number 6172089. They seem to be mostly knex pieces. There is an interesting grey square like the base of some type of vehicle and some yellow spring pieces that are interesting.

[image: bag with knex type pieces in black, grey, red, yellow and light brown]
[[image: bag with knex type pieces in black, grey, red, yellow and light brown][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDs4w.jpg)

Answer (score 6):

This type of Lego is called [Technic](https://www.lego.com/en-nz/themes/technic).

Based on the parts I can see, it looks to be bag #1 of [McLaren Formula 1 Team 2022 Race Car](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=42141-1).

[image: McLaren]

I found this by [searching for sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?fromForm=Y&viewMulti=Y&itemType=P&itemNo1=2850b&itemSeq1=1&colorID1=86&itemNo2=32294&itemSeq2=1&colorID2=11&itemNo3=&itemSeq3=1&colorID3=&in=S) including both [Technic Engine Cylinder](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2850b&C=86), and [Technic Wishbone Suspension Arm](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32294&C=11), which turned two results. Only the McLaren had the other parts in the bag.

[image: 2850b]
[image: 32294]

Comment: Seeing "2017" year stamped on polybag I find this relationship to 2022 set a little odd. TLG usually don't produce parts 5 years in advance.

Comment: "2017" on the bag just means that the copyright on the bag itself is from 2017, the actual bag may be made years later, and filled with parts even more years later. The only relation you can possibly draw from a year on the bag to the set, is that the set is unlikely to be several years older ("several" because I suppose they might use newer bags if they make more copies of a set).

Comment: @Alex LEGO has tons of these odd copyright years on their parts - Their pick a brick cans still say 2002 on them!

Comment: @MMM Unlike PAB cans (which are plastic moulded and that can explain the old date - might be too expensive to update moulds), pictured polybag has its text printed, which is far easier to update.